90s TV series with hidden camera?
I'm looking for an English TV series (USA) which I love but I can't find it. It was taken in 90s, I think, and it was about a boy who had a lot of hidden cameras in his house. He knew what his sister and parents were doing, cause he had something like "command center" in his room. It was really funny! I need an English title. 

It reminded me of Dexter's Laboratory but  of course that's not it.

No, no, it wasn't cartoon but TV series with actors.

actually the account you asked your question was "unregistered", and this new one is now registered.

Info on unregistered accounts. Here's how to merge them: http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Bailey Kipper's P.O.V. (1996-97)

Bailey Kipper's young age, 11, is belied by his wit and
  sophistication. His father works at a local TV station and often
  brings home junked bits of technical equipment for his son to mess
  around with, for Bailey is an electronics wizard. He constructs an
  elaborate spy system with which, via miniature cameras (in a form of
  eyeballs) he has concealed all over the house and in his family's
  clothing (and even in the dog's collar), he can record the family's
  daily activity, creating a video diary of their lives. His viewing
  area is hidden away in a part of the house he has made inaccessible to
  the others. Each episode presented the results of Bailey's handiwork
  as he re-ran recent events in the lives of the Kipper family - mom,
  dad, little brother Eric and older sister Robin.  





Yesss!! This is it!!! Thank you so much, I was looking for it for ten years!! I'm so happy and grateful!!

@Magdalena  Dud you read my comments about your account(s)?

Could it be Raising Caines? It starred Judge Reinhold and Mel Harris, with Mat Botuchis and Michelle Williams as the children. I am having trouble finding details to confirm your memory, but the series was never released in the US, only abroad, and it came out in 1995. 
